# Why there is only one method in the define-syntax my-class?

Tags: racket, define-syntax

```
(define-syntax my-class
    (syntax-rules ()
        [(my-class <class-name> (<attr> ...) 
            (method (bigger-x other) (> x (other 'x))))
         (define (<class-name> <attr> ...)
           (lambda (msg)
             (cond [(equal? msg (quote <attr>)) <attr>] ... 
                   [(equal? msg 'bigger-x) (lambda (other) (> x (other 'x)))]
                   [else "Unrecognized message!"])))]))
```

This is not a good template. But it's good for explaining the syntax of `define-syntax`. I am confusing why there is only 1 method in the 4th line. Isn't the `quote <attr>` in the expression `[(equal? msg (quote <attr>)) <attr>]` also a method? Their structures are quite similar.

Comment: What is the context? Is the macro from a book or a web page?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't the `quote <attr>` in the expression `[(equal? msg (quote <attr>)) <attr>]` also a method?

Supposing you mean "function", then yes, but is a function that will be evaluated at run-time. `my-class`, for example, is a function that will be evaluated at compile-time, because it was defined with `define-syntax`.

It seems you are using `my-class` to expand the definition of the "method" `bigger-x`, which is a function that compares some value `x` to an argument. In this case the `cond` will be evaluated at run-time and `(quote <attr>)` will expand to a symbol if `<attr>` turns out to be an identifier. Without some context is hard to know what `x` might be (and will raise an exception if no variable `x` is found at run-time), and the way that `my-class` is defined will require that you always pass `(method (bigger-x other) (> x (other 'x)))` (or a similar syntax, since `method`, `bigger-x`, etc will be bound as variables) for it to match a valid syntax.